# Java Swing Key Press Event

Tags: java, swing, focus, keypress

I am using my predefined inherited Focus Traversal Class For My JFrame

I have defined the key press event for one of my button with some action on pressing Tab key to select other tab of my jTabbed Pane . This button is not responding only for the tab key .

```
   int index=1;


    if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) 
      {

          // wrap around

    if(evt.isShiftDown())
    {

      KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusPreviousComponent();

    }   
    else
    {
     System.out.print("Shift Up");

      KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent();
      jtabPaneProducts.setSelectedIndex(index);
    }
    }
```

Please guide me how can i made jbutton to respond to the TAB key press in addition to focus traversal functionality.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be interested to read [How to Write a Key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html):

> Alternatively, you can use the KeyEventDispatcher class to pre-listen to all key events. The focus page has detailed information on the focus subsystem.

And consequently: [Interface KeyEventDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyEventDispatcher.html)